# Partial scaling on relative layout

Tags: java, android, scale, android-relativelayout

I'm currently working on a game and have designed a custom keyboard as a relative layout. The keyboard is displayed fine on mdpi and hdpi screens, but on xhdpi even with a provided resource it's not being displayed properly. This is my keyboard in xml:

http://pastebin.com/WR88j01C

And this is how it looks on an hdpi screen:
[image]

And this is how it looks on an ldpi screen(exactly the same thing happens on xhdpi):

[image]

As you can see the first 5 letters in each row are resized and the others are normal, I can't figure it out and I've tried.

EDIT:

styles.xml - http://pastebin.com/6FPnybzP

FontImageButton class - http://pastebin.com/FgeG1aJ9

Comment: can you post the styles.xml?
and FontImageButton class?

Comment: @Andrey E Sorry, was away, posting right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to your your buttons

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It actually solved it, I can't believe it! Thank you so much!
Can you explain the reasoning?

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning?

Comment: @mts Sorry for delay. As i know buttons have a minimal height and width typically of 48dp. So if you want really small button, you have to set this attributes directly.